# Using underscorejs to flattern array by nested array item

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have array of objects that each object have list and each nested list contain 1 and 2.

```
[{
    "name":"a",
    "companies":[1,2]
},
{
    "name":"b",
    "companies":[1,2]
},
{
    "name":"c",
    "companies":[1,2]
}]
```

I want create dupplicted list by underscorejs like this:

```
[{
    "name":"a",
    "company":1
},
{
    "name":"a",
    "company":2
},
{
    "name":"b",
    "company":1
},
{ 
    "name":"b",
    "company":2
},
{
    "name":"c",
    "company":1
},
{
    "name":"c",
    "company":2
}]
```

How can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I've attempted it with underscore.

```
function makeCompany(name) {
  return function (company) {
    return { name: name, companies: company };
  }
}

function splitCompany(obj) {
  return _.map(obj.companies, makeCompany(obj.name));
}
```

For each object in the array, use `splitCompany` to create and return two objects based on the `companies` data, then flatten the returned array.

```
var result = _.flatten(_.map(arr, splitCompany));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2ytdbnvw/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without `underscore.js` as well. Following is a pure js version:

```js
var data = [{
    "name":"a",
    "companies":[1,2]
},
{
    "name":"b",
    "companies":[1,2]
},
{
    "name":"c",
    "companies":[1,2]
}];

var result = [];
data.forEach(function(item){
  item.companies.forEach(function(company){
    result.push({"name": item.name, "company": company});
  });
});

console.log(result);
```